# How do I access the properties of a data-sly-list item in Sightly?

Tags: sling, sightly

I am using Sightly with Sling 8 ( not AEM ). I have the following template:

```
<div data-sly-list.child="${resource.listChildren}">
    ${child.name}  |  ${child.path} | ${child.properties['jcr:title'] || 'no title'} 
</div>
```

The output ( for a single child ) is

```
hello_world | /content/blog/posts/hello_world | no title
```

I know there is a jcr:title property on the child resource as I have confirmed it using an HTTP call.

How can I access the properties on the `child` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `child` is a [Resource](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling8/org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource.html) which does not have getProperties() but has `getValueMap()`, so you should use:

```
${child.valueMap.jcr:title || 'no title'}
```

Note 1: Colons are allowed in variable names to support typical JCR names like `jcr:title`.

Note 2: getValueMap() is only available since Sling API 2.7.0 bundle, previously only `resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class)` was possible, which the expression language in sightly does not support, and this workaround was required: [AEM 6.0 Sightly Child Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689443/aem-6-0-sightly-child-nodes)